# How does one construct an affine variety morphism from an algebra homomorphism between their coordinate rings?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

$K$ denotes an algebraically closed field.

---

My course states that the category of affine varieties is equivalent to the opposite if the category of finitely generated reduced $K$-algebras.

If $V \subset \mathbb K^n$, $W \subset \mathbb K^m$ are affine varieties then I define a morphism of affine varieties as a map $\phi : V \rightarrow W$ such that the image of $\phi^* : K[W] \rightarrow  K^V :f \mapsto f \circ \phi$ is contained in $K[V]$ where $K[V],K[W]$ denote the coordinate rings of $V$ and $W$, and $K^V := \{g : V \rightarrow K \}$.

I've managed to show that these construction give a functor from affine varieties $\mathbf{Aff}_K$ to the opposite of $K$-algebras $\mathbf{Alg}_K^{op}$.

Conversely if I have a finitely generated reduced $K$ algebra $A$ then I can find a surjective homomorphism $\pi : K[x_1,...,x_m] \rightarrow A$, let $I = \ker \pi$ be a radical ideal (since $A$ reduced) and obtain an affine variety $V(I)$ from $I$ embedded in $\mathbb K^n$. Obviously $\pi$ is not unique so we could have obtained an affine variety $V(J) \subset K^m$ for some radical ideal $J = \ker \pi' \rhd K[y_1,...y_m].$

---

I have two questions which are closely related.

Question 1 :  The coordinate rings of these two affine varieties are both isomorphic to $A$ by the first isomorphism theorem so I suspect that this means that the varieties are isomorphic. But how can I prove that I have $\phi : V(I) \rightarrow V(J)$ such that $\phi^*$ is an isomorphism.

Question 2: To define a functor I need to obtain a morphism of affine varieties from algebra homomorphism between finitely generated reduced $K$ algebras. i.e. if $A,B$ are finitely generated reduced $K$ algebras with $\alpha : A \rightarrow B$ with $A \cong K[x_1,...,x_n]/I$ and $B \cong K[y_1,...,y_m]/J$ how can I get an affine morphism
$\phi : V(J) \rightarrow V(I)$ ?

Comment: An affinie variety morphism $V(I)\to V(J), x\to \phi(x)$ (varieties and morphism defined over $k$) is the same as a coordinate ring homomorphism $k[y]/J\to k[x]/I, f(y)\to f(\phi(x))$

Comment: I meant $k$-algebra homomorphism (so it is defined solely by the images of the $y_j$ in $k[x]/I$)

Comment: @reuns Of Course !!! I get it. Thanks a lot